# Express4 app.get don't wait library call for continue

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express 4 node application with following.

My problem is app.get don't wait to finish exectuion of getAllFsRiver and return nothing.

How to do this?

in app.js

```
var api1 = require('./routes/api1.js');
app.use(api1) ;
```

in route/api1.js

```
*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
module.exports = express();
var app = module.exports;
var esclient = require('../lib/esclient') ;

/* GET api vers 1 . */
app.get('/api/1/settings/rivers/fs*', function (req, res) {
    var allriver = esclient.getAllFsRiver() ;
    console.log("route");
    res.json(allriver);
```

Here res.json is called before esclient.getAllFsRiver has finish execution

Comment: Probably your `getAllFsRiver()` function is asynchronous. Please post the `esclient` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `getAllFsRiver` is asynchronous and probably takes a callback.  You should pass a callback to the function and handle the response within the callback.

```
esclient.getAllFsRiver(function (err, json) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).end();
    }
    res.json(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add comment. Could you add **getAllFsRiver** implementation to the question? Maybe it is an async call.

Answer (score 0):

You have must write you route kind of:

```
*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.get('/api/1/settings/rivers/fs*', function (req, res) {
    var allriver = esclient.getAllFsRiver() ;
    console.log("route");
    res.json(allriver);
   /* ... */
})

module.exports = router;
```

In you code you exporting from you route new express app, that wrong

Answer (score 0):

adding a callback ti my function. Ok

Comment: /* GET api vers 1 . */
app.route('/api/1/settings/rivers/fs*')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        esclient.getAllFsRiver(function(result) {
            console.log("route");
            res.json(result);

        });
    })